# Member Functions C++ beginner

Tags: c++, class, member-functions

So basically I am toying around with a simple employee class that is suppose to map a name to a unique id number. Now here's the thing. I want to create a member function that takes no arguments but returns the map of the name and employee id. I want the call to be intuitive eg. `employee.map_this() // returns a map`

```
class Employee
{
public:
    Employee() = default;
    Employee(const string& pname);  
    Employee& operator=(const Employee&) = delete; 
    Employee(const Employee&) = delete;

private:
    const string name;
    static int ID_no;
    const string employee_ID;
    map<const string, const string> map_this();
};

int Employee::ID_no = 0001;

Employee::Employee(const string& pname) : name(pname), employee_ID(to_string(ID_no))
{ 
    ID_no++;
}

map<const string, const string> Employee::map_this() 
{
    //     How do I do this????
}
```

Comment: Do you want to return a [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) or a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)? Wouldn't map be an overkill here? Maps are generally used in classes which manage many objects while this is a per-object data that you want to return in a single function call.

Comment: Where is the map data member?

Comment: @0x499602D2: Be it he wants map or pair, it doesn't matter if there's a corresponding data member, one can be created on the fly.

Comment: Consider using `std::tuple`, or something like that, to save `id` and `name` together, and return them with your `map_this` function. `std::map` is intended to store lots of key->value pairs, not one.

Answer (score 0):

`std::map` is not what you think it is. A map is used when you want to for instance map all employee Id numbers to their respective `Employee` objects.

If you want to return two values as one object then I suggest you use `std::pair`.

```
std::pair<const std::string, const std::string> Test::getNameAndId() {
    return {name, employee_ID};
}
```

And then you can acces the name and id in the `std::pair` like this:

```
Employee employee{"Carl"};
auto& p = employee.getNameAndId();
std::cout << "Name: " << p.first << ", Id: " << p.second << std::endl;
```

Outputs:

```
Name: Carl, Id: 1
```